# How to get onToch event absolute position and comparing it with imageView coordinates?

Tags: android, imageview, touch, swipe, touch-event

I'm basically trying to edit the content of an editText by swiping on multiple ImageViews.
Here is my code but nothing seems to work.

```
package com.example.touchdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout relLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
     final TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     final ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     final ImageView myImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

     myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
     {

         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
         {
             int x,y;

               if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                   Rect rect = new Rect();
                        rect.left = myImageView.getLeft();
                        rect.top = myImageView.getTop();
                        rect.bottom = myImageView.getBottom();
                        rect.right = myImageView.getRight();
                    Rect rect2 = new Rect();
                        rect2.left = myImageView2.getLeft();
                        rect2.top = myImageView2.getTop();
                        rect2.bottom = myImageView2.getBottom();
                        rect2.right = myImageView2.getRight();
                     x = (int) event.getRawX();
                     y = (int) event.getRawX();
                     if(rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        txtv.append("Ti ho trovato 1");
                     }
                     else if(rect2.contains(x, y)) {
                            txtv.append("Ti ho trovato 2");
                     }

                }
            //  txtv.append("ciao");

                     return false;
         }   

    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is my xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

I think that the best way is to get the Event coordinates based on full screen dimension and the checking if they are contained in the rectangles representing my imageViews.
Also I'd like to figure out if in my code the onTouch event is invoked continuously.
I'd be grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for whether the touch listener records a touch within the rect defined by your imageview. However, you're only checking that when in an ACTION_MOVE event.  You probably want to catch the initial touch(es) with ACTION_DOWN, which is defined to be on the view.  ACTION_MOVE is when you've already touched the view and are moving your finger